# JavaFX. Переменная в FXML

Tags: java, javafx

Доброго времени суток!

Начал изучать JavaFX и не могу разобраться в работе переменных в FXML документе.
Допустим, мне нужно получить размер экрана. В главном классе я бы прописал так:

```
Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int height = sSize.height;
int width  = sSize.width;
```

Но как мне сделать это в FXML документе?

Можно как-то передать переменную из класса в FXML документ, или как-то нужно получить её в самом документе?

Answer (score 2):

Хотя можно написать так:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="Controller">
    <fx:define>
        <Double fx:id="myDouble" fx:value="500.0"/>
    </fx:define>
    <Button fx:id="button1" prefWidth="$myDouble" text="Click Me!" />
</AnchorPane>
```

Однако ценности такой вариант почти не представляет по двум причинам:

Во-первых, изменить в контроллере значение переменной типа `Double` нельзя, так как объекты этого класса немутабельны - ведь в классе `Double` нет какого-нибудь `set()` или `setValue()`,
а при присвоении (к примеру, `myDouble=123.0;`) создается новый объект типа `Double`, ссылку на который кнопка уже не знает.

Во-вторых, эта переменная не является JavaFx-свойством. Так, если попробовать пойти по упрощенному пути и сделать простой класс-обертку, позволяющий изменять значение, 
то кнопка интерфейса все равно не узнает об изменениях значения в контроллере.

Для того, чтобы управлять шириной кнопки из контроллера следует либо "вытащить" аннотацией `@FXML` в контроллер саму кнопку, либо использовать какой-нибудь класс в стиле бина JavaFx (с JavaFx-свойствами), к свойству которого можно привязать ширину кнопки, например, такой:

`// my/DoubleBean.java:`

```
package my;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class DoubleBean {
    private SimpleDoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public void setValue(double value){
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }

    public DoubleBean() {
    }
}
```

Пример использования бина такого класса (чуть-чуть интереснее, чем изменение ширины кнопки):

В этом примере создается окно в пол-экрана шириной, с двумя кнопками, которыми можно увеличить или уменьшить ширину окна.
Три свойства ширины окна привязываются к свойству `value` инструкцией односторонней привязки `${myWidth.value}`. Начальное значение (333.0) устанавливается
в fxml, но сразу после создания объектов `FXMLLoader` вызывает метод `initialize()` контроллера, где это свойство изменяется на половину ширины экрана.

Необычной особенностью этого примера является то, что `Stage` прописан прямо в fxml-файле и при создании не станет "primary" (такое решение, вероятно, не подойдет для апплетов).

`// my/sample.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.stage.Stage?>
<?import my.DoubleBean?>

<Stage xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
       fx:controller="my.Controller"
       width="${myWidth.value}"
       minWidth="${myWidth.value}"
       maxWidth="${myWidth.value}"
       fx:id="myStage">
    <fx:define>
        <DoubleBean fx:id="myWidth" value="333"/>
    </fx:define>
    <scene>
        <Scene>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER">
                <Button text="Сделать шире" onAction="#makeWider"/>
                <Button text="Сделать уже" onAction="#makeNarrower"/>
            </VBox>
        </Scene>
    </scene>
</Stage>
```

`// my/Controller.java:`

```
package my;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;

public class Controller {
    public Stage myStage;
    public DoubleBean myWidth;

    public void initialize() {
        myWidth.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                System.out.println(observable + ": " + oldValue + " -> " + newValue)
        );
        myWidth.setValue(getScreenWidth()/2);
    }

    public void makeWider(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (myWidth.getValue() < getScreenWidth()) {
            myWidth.setValue(myWidth.getValue() + 100);
            myStage.centerOnScreen();
        }
    }

    public void makeNarrower(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (myWidth.getValue() > 200) {
            myWidth.setValue(myWidth.getValue() - 100);
            myStage.centerOnScreen();
        }
    }

    private double getScreenWidth() {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    }
}
```

`// my/Main.java:`

```
package my;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно передать данные в FXML файл при помощи [DI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

В контролере который отвечает за представление можно получить элемен по ID

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="dev.gva.ui.MainController">
   <Label fx:id="label1"></Label> <!--Дать ИД элементу который хочешь получить-->
</VBox>
```

В контроллере пожно получить элемен :

```
@FXML
public Label label1; // Имя переменной должно совпадать с ИД
```

Пример:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable{
    
    @FXML
    public Label label1;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
       Rectangle2D r = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
       int height = r.getHeight();
       int width  = r.getWidth();
       label1.setText("Hello world: " + height + ", " + width);
    }
```

https://github.com/gvart/RRPlayer - Посмотри может поможет

Comment: Он вроде хочет извратиться наоборот - получить данные из контроллера в FXML.

Comment: Так в этом и суть, в контроллере ты получаешь через DI элемент UI. В initialize методе получаешь данные которые тебе надо и передаешь в представление.

Comment: @GVArt, не могу понять, в чем проблема?


FXML:
`<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="di.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
<Integer fx:id="width"></Integer>
<Button fx:id="button1" prefWidth="#width" text="Click Me!" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>`


Controller:
`public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
@FXML
int width;
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
width  = sSize.width;}
}`

Comment: @TrueASL posmotri obnivlenii kod v otvete, i ne peredavai daniei v integer type a peredavai v kakoi libo komponent. Toest' polu4i `@FXML Button button1;` i v `init` metode ustanavi `button1.setWidth(r,getWidth());`

Comment: @GVArt,вы не дали ответ на вопрос. Вы мне показали,как просто получить элемент из FXML,а уже в контролере,в initialize,задать ему какие-либо параметры. Я же хочу просто передать переменную в FXML из контролера,чтобы использовать её в самом FXML.
Чтобы не в initialize прописывать `button1.setWidth(r,getWidth());`,а в FXML,с помощью полученной из контролера переменной,записать так `<Button fx:id="button1" prefWidth="#width" text="Click Me!" />`

Comment: Результат тот же. Ты не можешь делать какие либо операции либо хранить переменные в fxml это лишь декларативный стиль написание UI. Как ты говоришь "передать данные в fxml" - нет. Ты можешь в данном случае лишь присвоить это к какому либо элементу UI

Answer (score 0):

немного непонятное желание, но предложу свой вариант:

В самом fxml файле вместо размеров поставьте метку (шаблон для замены).

Перед инициализацией всего GUI, получите размер экрана. Отредактируйте файл заменив шаблон на размеры и сохраните в новый файл из него уже инициализируйте GUI. Как заставить javaFX использовать переменную ещё не созданного объекта не особо представляю.

В идеале зачем изобретать велосипед? Контроллер для этого и создан, чтобы инициализировать GUI в том виде в котором нужен, если какие-то параметры будут известны только во время работы, помимо его основного назначения